# validar select cuando no han seleccionado ninguna opcion en react native

Tags: react-native

buen dia, tengo un select en react native pero necesito validar en mi formulario que cuando no haya ninguna opcion seleccionada se dispare un evento al darle clic en un botón, tengo un algoritmo que me valida cualquier campo input pero no he podido con el select, les agradezco si me puden colaborar.

si fuera con campo textinput para evaluar me funcionaria sin problemas y me mostraria un alert si el campo esta vacio pero no he podido con el select "no he podido capturar el evento"

```js
import RNPickerSelect, { defaultStyles }  from 'react-native-picker-select';
    export const Pagina6Screen = ({navigation}) => {
    const [errorEmail,setErrorEmail ] = useState("")
    const [errorConfirm,setErrorConfirm ] = useState("")
    const registerUser =()=>{
      if(!validateData()){
        return;
      }
      //evento si ha seleccionado algo en el select
      navigation.replace('Pagina7Screen')
    }
    const validateData = () =>{
       setErrorConfirm("")
       setErrorEmail("")
       let isvalid = true
       if(!miselect){
        Alert.alert(
          "CAMPO OBLIGATORIO",
          "NO SELECCIONO NADA EN EL SELECT",
          [
            {
              text: "Aceptar",
              style: "cancel",
              
            },
          ],
          {
            cancelable: true,      
          }
        );
        isvalid = false
       }
       setErrorEmail("*")
       return isvalid
    }
    //select
    const miselect = {
      label: 'T.Doc',
      value: null,
      color: '#9EA0A4'
      
    };
    <RNPickerSelect 
    onValueChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
    placeholder={miselect}
    items={[
    { label: 'Cedula', value: 'Cedula' },
    { label: 'Pasaporte', value: 'Pasaporte' }
    ]}
    style={{
    inputAndroid: {
    borderColor:"black",
    }
    }}
<TouchableOpacity
           onPress={() => registerUser()}        
          >
              <Image source={require('../assets/guardar.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que mencionas, necesitas apoyarte del método **onValueChange** del componente **RNPickerSelect**.

Usando ese método puedes guardar el valor de la opción seleccionada en tu state y luego hacer la validación que necesitas.

Algo así:

```
const Pagina6Screen = () => {
  const [otionsSelected, setOptionsSelected] = useState<string | undefined>();

const validateData = () => {
    if (otionsSelected) {
      // Una opción ya fue seleccionada
    } else {
      // No se ha seleccionado ninguna opción
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RNPickerSelect
        onValueChange={value => {
          setOptionsSelected(value);
        }}
        items={[
          {label: 'Cedula', value: 'Cedula'},
          {label: 'Pasaporte', value: 'Pasaporte'},
        ]}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={validateData}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/guardar.png')} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Espero mi ejemplo te sirva